# Как передать несколько объектов в шаблон Django?

Tags: python, html, django

Сейчас из `views.py` в шаблон передается только `object_list`. Я хочу сделать так, чтобы еще передавался `query`. Как это сделать?

```py
class SearchResultsView(ListView):
    template_name = 'main_na/search_results.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        object_list = Posts.objects.filter(
            Q(title__icontains=query) | Q(author__username__icontains=query)
        )
        return object_list
```

Comment: Переопределить метод get_context_data https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#adding-extra-context